# Clipper library polygon and point intersection

Tags: geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

I am running `clipper_console_demo.cpp` compiled to `a.out` with following arguments:

Subject.txt:

```
50 50,
```

Clip.txt:

```
100 100,
100 0,
0 0,
0 100,
```

`./a.out Subject.txt Clip.txt INTERSECTION`

However the output 'solution.svg' is empty (there is only an outline of clipping polygon but not the subject). I also tried to change the orientation of the clipping square but solution is also empty.

Is it not possible to compute point/polygon intersection?

If not, what other combinations of subject/clip are not possible? As I understood from the doc, the clip has to be closed, but there are no other restrictions.

Comment: Your subject appear to have a single coordinate. Clipper will intersect polygons (closed paths) and polylines (open paths) but not single coordinates.

Comment: @Agnus thanks! I also noticed the following behaviour: when `clip` is  `2048 2048, 0 2048, 0 0` and is closed, `subject` is `0 0, 0 2048` and is open the solutions `GetFirst().Contour` is  `0 0,0 2048` however on the following page: http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/Units/ClipperLib/Classes/PolyTree/_Body.htm it says that top-most PolyNode's contour is always empty. However `OpenPathsFromPolyTree` works as expected. Is this behaviour expected?

Comment: @Agnus Actually the same applies when subject is the same as clipper. The contour is not empty.

Comment: @Agnus sorry, I misunderstood. GetFirst() actually returns the first child. Nevermind my previous comments.

Comment: For point intersection you can use the PointInPolygon function in the Clipper library.